# sed finding | and replacing with " quotation marks

Tags: replace, sed, find

I need to replace each `|` with `"` everywhere in a text file.
I have tried this below and many other variations and I cannot get it to work.

```
sed -i 's/"|"/"\""/g' workingfolder/start.txt > workingfolder/sortish.txt
sed -i 's/"|"/"\""/g' workingfolder/start.txt > workingfolder/sortish.txt
```

I really hope someone can help me.

Comment: You are wildly over-quoting. `sed 's/|/"/g'`

Answer (score 1):

this??

```
echo "||||"|sed 's/|/"/g'
""""
```

If this was what you were looking for,

- you don't have to quote chars in `s/../..` expression
- you can wrap quote (single/double) with the other (double/singel).